# Update 2 properties at once in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Look at Windows Power Options, there are two combo-boxes in `turn off the display`, one is `Battery` and the other is `Plugged in`.

Now the requirement is the value in `Battery` should be always less than the value in `Plugged in`.

So if `Battery` is initially set as 25 minutes, and then `Plugged in` is set as 10 minutes, the value of `Battery` should be automatically changed to 5 minutes. **Changing one value can potentially affect the other.**

And the code is plain ViewModel implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private uint pluggedIn;
    public uint PluggedIn 
    {
        get { return pluggedIn;}
        set 
        {
            if (pluggedIn != value)
            {
                pluggedIn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PluggedIn");
            } 
        }
    } 
    public uint Battery{...} //the same implementation
}
```

I modify the setter to apply the rule.

```
        set 
        {
            if (pluggedIn != value)
            {
                pluggedIn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PluggedIn");

                if (Battery >= PluggedIn)
                {
                    Battery = FindTheValueLessThanPluggedIn(); //this can potentially modify the value of PluggedIn from the setter of Battery.
                }
            } 
        }
```

**The problem.**

You can see calling Bettery's setter can also potentially affect the value of PluggedIn, if I have other requirement, I will have to write some hard to read/maintain code just to implement this seemingly easy task.

**The question**

I can first calculate the final value of both properties, and I need an "atomic" operation that can update both properties at once (without affecting each other), and after this "atomic" operation is finished, fire the `PropertyChanged` event for the two properties to update UI.

**A Second Thought**

After reading my question after posting, I think I have already answered my own question- setting the backing field instead of calling setter, but other better way?

```
CalculateNewVaules(out newValue1, out newValue2);
pluggedIn = newValue1;
battery = newValue2;
OnPropertyChanged("PluggedIn");
OnPropertyChanged("Battery");
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
   set 
    {
        if (pluggedIn != value)
        {
            pluggedIn = value;

            if (Battery >= PluggedIn)
            {
                _battery = FindTheValueLessThanPluggedIn();
                OnPropertyChanged("Battery");
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("PluggedIn");
        }
```

Notice that the setter of Battery is never called.

The two `OnPropertyChanged` calls on a single property is how I've handled all my cases that are similiar to yours, and they work nicely.

Alternatively, I've also used this technique:

```
YourViewModel(){
  PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
}

void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Battery":
            PluggedIn = CalculateNewValueForPluggedIn();
            break;

        case "PluggedIn":
            Battery = CalculateNewValueForBattery();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code, if the new `_battery` value equals the old one, the event fires anyway. So you have to check it additionally here, which makes your code more like copy-paste (because you need to check this in the `Battery` setter too).

Comment: @dymanoid: well, notice the method name, "FindTheValueLessThanPluggedIn", by that definition, the event will be fired always if `Battery >= PluggedIn` evaluates true.

Comment: yes, that makes the difference, setting _battery instead of setter.

Comment: @Chris, I agree, but only in this particular case. I wouldn't suggest such an approach for general usage though.

Comment: @kennyzx, I generally agree with "H W" answer. That's how you should do it. Refactor the "keeping properties synchronous" logic out from the properties, and add listener. You can subscribe to `NotifyPropertyChanged` event.

Comment: I fail to see the usefulness of the 2nd technique, how does the centralized event listener stops firing `PropertyChangedHandler` again when it assign new value to a property?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to bind the OnChange events to your "atomic" methods that you implement in the ViewModel. These methods should calculate the final value for both dropdown menus and afterwards set the Properties PluggedIn and Battery. Thus you do not need to modify the setters of the Properties at all and in theory do not even need to delay firing the PropertyChanged event (let the Property setter do this for you).

By outsourcing all the logic to it's own method and keeping the setters simple, the Properties won't interfere with each other. Note however that while all restrictions will be fulfilled when you use your mask, this would allow you to override your restrictions by setting the Properties manually in the code.